# Have parent DIV height auto-size based on child DIV height

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container that encapsulates a number of child containers.  The child containers have heights depending on the amount of text they hold.  I would like the child containers to determine the height of the parent container.  So if a child container has a height of 40px, then the parent container height should be 80px.  If the child container has a height of 100px, then the parent container height should be 140px (40px fixed + 100px variable).

I've tried leaving the height of the parent container undefined or set as auto or set at 100%, but they all leave my parent container with a height that is too small to hold the child container.  If I give my parent container height a set pixel then the problem goes away.

My parent DIV with fixed height(divs behave as expected)

```
.resultsbox{
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: #DDD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

jsFiddle example with set height:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uj5FP/6/

My parent DIV with no height set(parent height isn't enough to hold child)

```
.resultsbox{
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: #DDD;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

jsFiddle with no height set:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uj5FP/7/

How do I make the parent height auto-adjust correctly?

Comment: Did you try adding top and/or bottom padding?

Comment: In your example, are the `.resultsbox` div's the parent container that need the 40px padding?

Comment: @MarcAudet yes the .resultsbox is the parent container

Comment: So you want each .resultsbox to be (content height)+40px and flowing one after each other down the page?

Comment: Hello! I posted an updated answer a couple of days ago and I just wanted to make sure that you review it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another attempt.  Wrap your absolutely place elements in `<div class='absolute-panel'>`:

```
<div class='resultsbox'>
    <div class='absolute-panel'>
        <div class='reviewtitle'>    
          <strong>Fun</strong>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        <div class='reviewstatsright'>    
            <span class='text-info'>
                <dt>Rate</dt><dd>$50</dd>
            </span>
            <span class='text-info'>
                <dt>Tip</dt><dd>$10</dd>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div><!-- .absolute-panel -->
    <div class='reviewbody'>
        <p>What a great time!</p>
         <cite>-Rodger</cite>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
.absolute-panel {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 800px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

For the `.resultsbox`, take out the absolute positioning...

```
.resultsbox {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-color: #DDD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

For the `.reviewbody` take out the absolute positioning...  and add 40px bottom padding (if needed):

```
.reviewbody {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

**Comment**
I added some colored borders to keep track of things and these can be removed.

The trick is to define a fixed height panel to add all your precisely positioned elements.

After this, add your review body which has a variable height.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8mRVp/

Comment: Hi Marc, if you look at the fiddle with the fixed parent height, you'll notice that there are child DIVs inside of the DIV class 'resultsbox'.  The instances of 'resultsbox' make up the DIV ID 'reviews'.  The child DIV 'reviewbody' inside of the 'resultsbox' class will have variable heights.  Every other child DIV inside of 'resultsbox' will have fixed heights.  I would like the 'reviewbody' DIV to pass its height to the 'resultsbox' class DIVs.

Comment: Are you trying to do some exact arithmetic based on the height of `.reviewbody`?  Or do you simply want some whitespace after all the content within `.resultsbox`?

Comment: All of the rest of the child DIVs in 'resultsbox' class DIVs have a fixed height.  Let's say in this case they have a height of 50px combined.  The child DIV 'reviewbody' will have differing heights depending on how long the review is.  So if I have a 'reviewbody' DIV with a paragraph, it might take up 100px of height space.  In this case, this particular instance of 'resultsbox' should be 150px tall(50px fixed + 100px from 'reviewbody').

Comment: The height of the `.resultsbox` will expand automatically to the height of the fixed height elements and the variable height element, plus any padding and borders.  What am I missing?

Comment: If you look at the second fiddle in the original question, you'll notice that this isn't the case

Comment: I just noticed that you are using a lot of absolutely positioned elements.  I think I understand what you are concerned about... let me work on this.

Comment: Ah, I see what was happening, it wasn't so much the positioning as it was the set height on some of the divs

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things on this page you could do different and much simpler, but that is a different conversation.

I think what you are really asking about is clear fix options. The most basic is just adding overflow:hidden to the parent element.

And another option that I use for clear fix is: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

The difference is, if you have any content spilling out of the box, overflow:hidden will hide it and micro clearfix will show it.

Comment: Here is a simplified version. I made a lot of assumptions. http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/64TTF/

Comment: It seems you changed almost all of the original CSS.  This is just a small snippet of a larger website so the original CSS serves a purpose and needs to be kept